# Visual Studio 2015 RC - Build Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I have a Azure Service Fabric project, every time I modify the configuration files (ApplicationManifest.xml and ServiceManifest.xml), save them and build solution, Visual Studio discards my changes and reloads the old configuration files, after displaying the below dialog box. What could be the reason for the same?

[image]

Comment: Hi Sajad, what parts of your Application/Service manifests are you trying to modify? Some manifest sections are generated automatically and will overwrite your changes.

Answer (score -1):

When you build a service fabric project, the project system updates the application manifest to make sure all services are describe as needed.  If you have the application manifest file open at the time, you are prompted to reload it.

We just released the public preview release of Service Fabric and updated tools, please install those from Web Platform Installer.